# apache ignore htaccess and reach tomcat

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I've have a java application running on tomcat and i'm using the apache mod_proxy module to pass the files to tomcat, however tomcat seems to be ignore the .htaccess files, here my vhost.conf. How can I instruct apache to read the .htaccess

```
< Proxy *>

        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all

< /Proxy>

    ProxyRequests           Off
    ProxyPreserveHost   On
    ProxyPass               /   http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse        /   http://localhost:8080/
```

my htaccess got one rule as

```
RewriteRule ^/login(.*)$ /system/customer/portal/1$1 [R]
```

my apache ignore it and reach tomcat right away ..

i was trying to use

```
ProxyPass /login !
```

but no success , any tips ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ProxyPassMatch` for this with `regex` for excluding these locations:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(login|system/customer/portal/) !
```